# Error Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, guid

Got an error

"Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)"

The GUID input is "68f0eaed-189e-4c65-8cf8-475539d6f21b"

---

```
    context.Countries.AddRange(GetCountryData(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "csv", "country.csv")));

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();


    public List<Data.Country> GetCountryData(string filePath)
    {
        string csvRead = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        string[] csvFileRecord = csvRead.Split('\n');
        List<Data.Country> dataRecordList = new List<Data.Country>();

        foreach (var row in csvFileRecord.Skip(1))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
            {
                var cells = row.Split(',');
                var dataRecord = new Data.Country
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse(cells[0]),
                    Code = cells[1],
                    Name = cells[2]
                };
                dataRecordList.Add(dataRecord);
            }
        }

        return dataRecordList;
    }
```

---

CSV file

```
"id","code","name"
"68f0eaed-189e-4c65-8cf8-475539d6f21b","AX","Åland Islands"
"76cf600f-7bf6-40fb-8803-142eac60f3dd","AL","Albania"
...
```

**EDITED** Updated code, it now gets the correct GUID value yet an error still occurs

```
My input "68f0eaed-189e-4c65-8cf8-475539d6f21b"

fail: MyApp.ContextSeed[0]
      Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT CASE
          WHEN EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM public.country AS c)
          THEN TRUE::bool ELSE FALSE::bool
      END
```

Comment: `Guid.Parse` on the string you show in the question works just fine; so: we must deduce that the value of `cells[1]` is **not** actually the string that you think it is. So: write out exactly what the value is, including any leading / trailing whitespace. Perhaps `if(!Guid.TryParse(cells[1], out var guid)) Console.WriteLine($"'{cells[1]}'");`

Comment: I tried 68f0eaed-189e-4c65-8cf8-475539d6f21b it works correctly. probably your row is incorrect

Comment: Are you sure that Guid is in column 1 and not 0? Indexes count from 0...

Comment: edited see csv file format above

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yeah guid is on 0 not 1 :) ... however skip doesnt work!

Comment: csvFileRecord.Skip(0); does not skip the first row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to change the code to the following:

```
public List<Data.Country> GetCountryData(string filePath)
    {
        string csvRead = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        string[] csvFileRecord = csvRead.Split('\n');
        List<Data.Country> dataRecordList = new List<Data.Country>();

        foreach (var row in csvFileRecord.Skip(1))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
            {
                var cells = row.Split(',');
                var dataRecord = new Data.Country
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse(cells[0].Replace("\"", "")),
                    Code = cells[1].Replace("\"", ""),
                    Name = cells[2].Replace("\"", "")
                };
                dataRecordList.Add(dataRecord);
            }
        }

        return dataRecordList;
    }
```

With the information you just added, it is clear that you are trying to convert a string, that is not a Guid, to a Guid. Note the new indexes at `cells`. Also `csvFileRecord.Skip(1);` didn't skip anything; now it should work, because a new `IEnumerable` is returned in the `foreach`'s head.
Also note that you will need to remove the `"` characters from the `cells`!

Comment: Updated code, it now gets the correct GUID value yet an error still occurs (see error message in OP)